# What is Tendency of RVR?

Tags: weather, visibility, asos

What does tendency of RVR (Runway Visual Range) mean and why down and up have the same values?

[image]

*This is from AWOS(Automated Weather Observing System)*

Comment: that same value for up and down must be a typo!

Comment: can you provide a link to the document you extracted the table from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When included as part of the RVR, the tendency indicates whether it is trending up (improving), down (deteriorating) or there is no change. It is usually indicated by the suffix `U` or `D`.

When reported in a METAR it means that in the 10 minutes preceeding the observation, the mean RVR in the first 5 minutes varied from the mean RVR is the second 5 minutes by 100m or more.

An example would be `R12/P1200U`

- Runway 12
- Greater than 1200m
- Improving

Comment: Thanks @mins I was really struggling to find something that matched my knowledge

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Considering Metar, you're right. The message type in my case is awos not metar. So if the tendency value is 1 it means a tendecy exists, if 0 it means a tendency doesn't exist.

Comment: Better reference in ICAO [Doc 9328](http://www.icscc.org.cn/upload/file/20190102/Doc.9328-EN%20Manual%20of%20Runway%20Visual%20Range%20Observing%20and%20Reporting%20Practices.pdf#page=93): Table 11-2.   Detailed structure of RVR information included in METAR and SPECI.

Comment: @mins that's the one I found, but as it was Chinese I wasnt sure it was a very good (ICAO) reference.